# Unable to render props in a page from Styled Components object

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm having troubles controlling the appearance of my button from different pages and components.

**button.js**

```
const Button = styled.button`
    background: ${props => props.lightbg ? 'linear-gradient(to right, #9969fb, #7833fc)' : 'linear-gradient(to right, #4813AC, #6239B2)'};
    box-shadow: ${props => props.lightborder ? "inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #6d49b5;" :  "inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #9168dd80;"};  
`

export default function ButtonPurple(props) {
    return (
        <Button>{props.btnText}</Button>
    )
}
```

In **index.js** I'm unable to change the button background, I can input both `true` and `false` but what is rendered is always the second value. Seems that the component accepts the prop only in **button.js** and not in other pages. Any explanation would be really appreciated. Thank you.

```
<Button lightbg={false} btnText="Discover Now"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to forward the properties to your styled button from the ButtonPurple component:

```
export default function ButtonPurple(props) {
    return (
        <Button lightbg={props.lightbg}>{props.btnText}</Button>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. I was able to control the props by just entering the prop name without true or false: <ButtonPurple lightbg lightborder btnText="Discover Now"/>.